# Non English characters not inserting from file to SQL Server in C# application

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, sql-server-2012

We have this table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PackageStatus] 
(
    [ID]                   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [PackageStatusName]    NVARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    [PackageStatusName_FR] NVARCHAR (200) NULL,
    [IsActive]             BIT            
        CONSTRAINT [DF_PackageStatus_IsActive] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [DisplayName]          NVARCHAR (200) 
        CONSTRAINT [DF_PackageStatus_DisplayName] DEFAULT ('') NOT NULL,
    [DisplayName_FR]       NVARCHAR (200) 
        CONSTRAINT [DF_PackageStatus_DisplayName_FR] DEFAULT ('') NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_PackageStatus] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);
```

`PackageStatus.sql` merge script which contains some french values

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[PackageStatus] ON 

MERGE [dbo].[PackageStatus] AS T
USING ( VALUES 
    (1, N'New', N'En transit', 1, N'In Transit', N'En transit'),
    (2, N'Received', N'Prêt pour le ramassage', 1, N'Ready for Pickup', N'Prêt pour le ramassage'),
    (3, N'Received Damaged', N'Prêt pour le ramassage', 1, N'Ready for Pickup', N'Prêt pour le ramassage'),
    (4, N'Scheduled', N'Programmé', 1, N'Scheduled', N'Programmé')
) AS S ([ID], [PackageStatusName], [PackageStatusName_FR], [IsActive], [DisplayName], [DisplayName_FR])
ON T.[ID] = S.[ID]
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE 
        SET 
            T.[PackageStatusName] = S.[PackageStatusName],
            T.[PackageStatusName_FR] =  S.[PackageStatusName_FR],
            T.[IsActive] = S.[IsActive],
            T.[DisplayName] =  S.[DisplayName],
            T.[DisplayName_FR] = S.[DisplayName_FR]         
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT ([ID], [PackageStatusName], [PackageStatusName_FR], [IsActive], [DisplayName], [DisplayName_FR])
        VALUES ([ID], [PackageStatusName], [PackageStatusName_FR], [IsActive], [DisplayName], [DisplayName_FR])
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    THEN DELETE;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[PackageStatus] OFF
```

If we run that script from SQL Server Management Studio, it works as expected.

[image]

But when we read that file content using C# and run SQL using Entity Framework Core from the application end

```
 string sql = File.ReadAllText(sourceFilePath);
 DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql);
```

we see unwanted characters

[image]

Again things are as expected if we use a hardcoded query

```
string sql = @"
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[PackageStatus] ON 
    MERGE [dbo].[PackageStatus] AS T
    USING ( VALUES 
        (1, N'New', N'En transit', 1, N'In Transit', N'En transit'),
        (2, N'Received', N'Prêt pour le ramassage', 1, N'Ready for Pickup', N'Prêt pour le ramassage'),
        (3, N'Received Damaged', N'Prêt pour le ramassage', 1, N'Ready for Pickup', N'Prêt pour le ramassage'),
        (4, N'Scheduled', N'Programmé', 1, N'Scheduled', N'Programmé')
    ) AS S ([ID], [PackageStatusName], [PackageStatusName_FR], [IsActive], [DisplayName], [DisplayName_FR])
    ON T.[ID] = S.[ID]
    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN UPDATE 
            SET 
                T.[PackageStatusName] = S.[PackageStatusName],
                T.[PackageStatusName_FR] =  S.[PackageStatusName_FR],
                T.[IsActive] = S.[IsActive],
                T.[DisplayName] =  S.[DisplayName],
                T.[DisplayName_FR] = S.[DisplayName_FR]         
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN INSERT ([ID], [PackageStatusName], [PackageStatusName_FR], [IsActive], [DisplayName], [DisplayName_FR])
            VALUES ([ID], [PackageStatusName], [PackageStatusName_FR], [IsActive], [DisplayName], [DisplayName_FR])
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
        THEN DELETE;
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[PackageStatus] OFF
";
DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql);
```

We have tried encoding, but nothing works

```
 string sql = File.ReadAllText(sourceFilePath, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Is there any way to resolve that issue?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 doesn't support UTF-8, which is the encode you are enforcing. UTF-8 support was added in SQL Server 2019 and you have to be using a UTF-8 collation to likely achieve what you're trying to do. But what you should be showing is your full C# code, not just a couple of snippets.

Comment: @Larnu i think the problem is the way c# loading the file, if we use hardcoded query, it worked expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
string sql = File.ReadAllText(sourceFilePath, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
```